# Unexpected "table index is nan" error lua

Tags: lua, love2d

I have the line

```
distanceTable[ tonumber(distance) ] = obj
```

Which is raising a "table index is nan" error. When distance is 67.882250993909. type(distance) returns "number"

Distance is a number so why am I getting this error?

Comment: `nan` is a number; for instance, `0/0` returns `nan` and `type(0/0)` is `"number"`. Can you give more code to show where this is happening and what the value of `distance` is when there's an error?

Comment: Why are you using `tonumber(distance)`?  Isn't `distance` already a number?  If `distance` is a string, then `type(distance)` may not be `number`.

Comment: tonumber(distance) was for demonstration purposes

Comment: It's strange because I don't recall ever getting `nan` as a result from `tonumber`, only a non-`nan` number or `nil`. I wonder what happened.

Comment: @cyclaminist, `tonumber(0/0)` gives `nan`.

Comment: @lhf, I guess I was thinking of cases where `tonumber` receives a non-number. I haven't find a string that `tonumber` converts to `nan` (`tonumber 'nan'` returns `nil` for instance).

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, NaN cannot be a key in a table, similarly to `nil`. I suppose this limitation is caused by the fact that there are many possible binary values for a NaN, and according to the IEEE standard, `NaN != NaN`.

Since `tonumber` cannot return a NaN when given a string, it must have come from `distance`. One of the results of the operations you used was probably undefined, and so it returned NaN. You can use `distance ~= distance` to check for NaN and handle it accordingly, or prevent the computation that resulted in the value.

Comment: `tonumber` returns NaN when given NaN, as in `tonumber(0/0)` for instance.